# Issue with cts:and-query in Marklogic

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic

I have some xml document. The structure of the documents are like this :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<patent-assignment>
  <assignment-record>
    <correspondent>
      <name>NORTH AMERICA INTERNATIONAL PATENT OFFIC</name>
      <address-1>P.O. BOX 506</address-1>
      <address-2>MERRIFIELD, VA 22116</address-2>
    </correspondent>
  </assignment-record>
  <patent-assignors>
    <patent-assignor>
      <assignor-name>TSAI, YU-WEN</name>
      <execution-date>
        <date>20050331</date>
      </execution-date>
    </patent-assignor>
    <patent-assignor>
      <assignor-name>HUANG, CHENG-I</name>
      <execution-date>
        <date>20050331</date>
      </execution-date>
    </patent-assignor>
  </patent-assignors>
  <patent-assignees>
    <patent-assignee>
      <assignee-name>FARADAY TECHNOLOGY CORP.</name>
      <address-1>NO.10-2, LI-HSIN ROAD 1, SCIENCE-BASED INDUSTRIAL PARK</address-1>
      <city>HSIN-CHU CITY</city>
      <country-name>TAIWAN</country-name>
    </patent-assignee>
  </patent-assignees>
</patent-assignment>
```

I have created fields on `assignor-name` and `assignee-name`. Now I am running the `cts:search` query like this:-

```
let $query:=cts:and-query((

    cts:element-query(xs:QName("assignor-name"), 
      cts:field-word-query("Assignor Name", "apple")),
    cts:element-query(xs:QName("assignee-name"), 
      cts:field-word-query("Assignee Name", "salix"))
  ))

for $x in cts:search(fn:doc(), $query)
return $x
```

where Assignor Name and Assignee Name are names of the fields which I have created. And these fields have `assignor-name` and `assignee-name` as their localname respectively. But when I am running this query it is giving me empty sequence. I have also checked my xml documents and documents have data where `assignor-name` is "apple" and `assignee-name` is "salix" still I am not getting the result. When I run this query only for assignor name or assignee name then I get results but when I combine them into an `and-query` then I did not get any results.  Please help.

Comment: Puneet, your sample data doesn't match what you're trying to do: your query is using a namespace ("pa:") that isn't shown in your data, as well as apple and salix not being there. Could you update with a sample that should match?

Answer (score 2):

Besides the namespace problem that Dave pointed out, the combination of `element-query` and `field-query` is unusual, and probably won't lead to satisfactory results.

For this query, you could drop both in favor of a simple `cts:element-word-query` on the element.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `cts:element-word-query` function in the following manner:

```
cts:and-query((cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("pa:assignor-name"),
                                      "apple",
                                      "case-insensitive"
                                      ),
              cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("pa:assignee-name"),
                                     "salix",
                                      "case-insensitive")
              ))
```